# Modify a local file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I must make a local app with an interface. This app should load text files, modify them, and save them.

I made the interface with html/css/js, and the core of the app was made with js only.

Currently, I load the file with an input, but to save it, the browser makes me download it. I know this is a security measure.

This app is not going to be put online.

My question is : what can I do to replace directly the loaded file by the new one ?

- Can I use my app (html/css/js) without a browser ?
- Is there a browser that allows me to edit my local files directly ?
- Is there any solution I can't think of ? Using another language to communicate with the js maybe ?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide the code you have tried

Comment: You should look at [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/), and then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067298/saving-files-locally-with-electron)

Comment: @user93 To download the file ? Something close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript/32858416#32858416).

Comment: @NathanP. I will definitely try this afternoon.

Comment: Several browsers now support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API), which can be used to modify files on the local disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need your app to be online, with [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) you can make an executable using your existing code (you will have change how you're going to save the file using Electron APIs).
Being a program running on your system, you'll be able to save directly on the file system.

Comment: I will definitely look into this this afternoon ! I'll keep you updated if it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: My Question: Then, how come https://app.diagrams.net/ can modify and save to local files if device option is chosen ?

Answer (score 0):

JS in the browser is not able to edit local files, because of security.

If you want to, you can use `Node.js`, a Desktop/Server Framework, which uses JS.

Comment: I don't know Node enough to see how it could help. Could you tell me very quick what could be done and how using Node ?

Comment: Node.js is just the framework, which let's you run JS on the Desktop/Server. Depending on your needs, you could use other frameworks like Electron (Desktop & Mac), Cordova & Ionic (Smartphone), which are also based on Node.js

Comment: If you need a GUI, i would recommend using Electron, it's simple to use and very well structured