# Writing file with electron/vue is not working

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron

I'm trying to write results of an electron/vue app to a file.

```
          const fs = require("fs");
      try {
        fs.writeFileSync(
          "myfile.txt",
          "the text to write in the file",
          "utf-8"
        );
      } catch (e) {
        alert(`Failed to save the file ${e}!`);
      }
```

As suggested here: [Saving files locally with electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067298/saving-files-locally-with-electron)

But I get an error: fs.writeFileSync does not exist.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: you don't use import statement for use libraries ? do you use vue-cli plugins for create your project ?

Comment: @darkomen - The require statement you can see as the first line. I'm not aware of any vue-cli plugins???

Comment: this vue-cli command : 'vue create vue-electron-app' can easily help you to create a base project for more easily do what you want.

Comment: @darkomen - I see, yes I use vue-cli.

Comment: I see now that fs is not for browser usage. Does this mean that there is no way to save files for use by the user in a electron app browser side?

Comment: perhaps send a IPC message to the main process for writing file

Answer (score 0):

The scripts running in web contexts don't have access to node or electron
functionality by default as a security precaution.  It's hard to find good
samples for the current version, there are too many outdated or non-working
samples out there.  I have a [sample repo](https://github.com/JasonGoemaat/vue-electron-test-app/tree/sample/open-file) where I communicate with the main thread to show an open file dialog and display the selected name and contents if you're interested.

The current way (Vue3, electron13) looks to be using [context isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation), creating
a [preload script](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts) that runs in the render thread and has access to node and electron functionality.

**1. Add configuration to vue.config.js**

This adds a `src/preload.js` script as a preload script to `pluginOptions.electronBuilder`.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js'
    }
  }
});
```

**2. Setup our plugin script in `background.js`**

When creating the window, add the preload script:

```js
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      enableRemoteModule: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') // add preload script
    }
  })
```

**3. Add `src/preload.js` script**

In this script we have more privileges and can use node functionality like 'fs'.   We can expose our own api to the web scripts:

```js
import { contextBridge } from 'electron'
import fs from 'fs'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('file', {
  save: (filePath, text) => {
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, text, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
  }
});
```

**4. Use `window.file.save()` in your code**

```js
try {
  window.file.save('myfile.txt', 'the text to write to the file');
} catch (e) {
  alert(`Failed to save the file ${e}!`);
}
```