# Do I need to check for localStorage support when using Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have started making desktop apps with `Electron`.I need to save some configuration into `localStorage`.I am using the latest version of Electron and I know that `localStorage` is supported.

Due to my previous experiences with my website I know that I have to check for `localStorage` support before doing something.

Do I need to do the same in Electron apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't - Electron is based on [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) which has [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) support for a very long time now.

#### Side note

In Electron, you can also read/write actual files using the file system which might be a better alternative for storing config files.

Since Chromium is not sandboxed when running in the way Electron runs it, you could also read/write actual text files just as you would in Node.js - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465034/where-to-store-user-settings-in-electron-atom-shell-application) explores those alternatives - or just go straight to using [electron-config](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-config)