# Saving cookies in Electron

Tags: python, flask, electron

I'm trying to implement a login system from my electron client, where I make a call to my RESTful API in Flask to authenticate. This is supposed to set a cookie onto Electron, but nothing is being saved to keep track of the session. Is there any way to save cookies in Electron from a call to a RESTful API to keep track of sessions? I'm sure that my RESTful API is working as intended.

Comment: Never used electron, but i'm sure `localStorage` exists, so you can store any value you want to store there. Also it's probably better to use Token Authentication for clients that don't reside on the same server as the backend API.

Comment: This question might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465034/where-to-store-user-settings-in-electron-atom-shell-application#30610157